# What is the .e filetype in C?

Tags: c, header, history

I was looking at getting [HTML-XML-Utils](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/) working on my computer and I noticed the .e filetype in the source tree. Running:

```
% file types.e
types.e: ASCII c program text
```

reveals some clues about it and its use in C files seems to be that of a header file.

Can anyone reveal some more information or history about this filetype? I've tried my best Google-foo but I cannot find anything.

Comment: There is no `.e` convention in C; `file` may be wrong. What do the first lines of the file look like?

Comment: Perhaps preprocessed source, since that is what is produced by `gcc -E`. But such would usually go into another `.c` or `.cpp` file.

Comment: Perhaps by studying the makefile you can understand the role of those .e files in the source tree.

Comment: @larsmans you're correct. After a little more fiddling with `file` I discovered that it's analysis is actually based on the content within the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never heard of that file type in connection with C before, but after checking the files and the Makefile it seems to be variables and functions that are *exported*, therefore the `.e` extension.

They seem to be created by a special program (which comes with the package) called `cexport` whose manual page states:

> cexport - create header file with exported declarations from a C file

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is the term "exported" referring to something in particular? (i.e. I might assume that the term is for using the functions in another programming language)

Comment: @casr No, it seems it just symbols that are used in other source files, i.e. function prototypes etc. The `.e` files are included in other source files with a normal `#include`-directive.